# Particle Settings - Noob - Blenderguru Tutorial

Tags: particles

New to Blender, I'm not sure why my Particle Effect isn't working here. I'm sure I've clicked a wrong option but I have no clue where. I've been following a Blenderguru tutorial on Youtube and this lesson added a 'Use Count' feature from the particle effects. However, when I enable it, the blue spheres are grouped in bands. Basically they don't look random.

I tried changing the seed number, no effect. I tried re-doing the step (deleted the sphere and set it up again), no effect. I've restarted PC.

Any ideas?

[Tutorial](https://youtu.be/aZ5ungDgFNc?t=1052)

[image: Use Count On]

[image: Use Count Off]

Comment: I think it maybe because you don't have enough particles to begin with? I've seen this weird clumping together of particles before. Try increasing the overall amount of particles and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

From a Youtube comment:

Johnathan Burkhardt
1 day ago
I had the same problem!  If you go to Particles > Render > Collection  there is a checkbox for "Pick Random."  I clicked that and it fixed the problem!

---

Sorry guys, I knew it was a noob problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Can you share the file? (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)
- why are you in frame 134?

You can create another emitter only for the "spheres", so it probably fixes your "group" problem.

Comment: Frame 134? Because I'm a noob.